# Coloring the name in resume

Tags: color, resume

I wish to color the name "\name{xxx}" in my resume. How can I do that? 
I'm using the template "Simple and Clear Your Username Resume".

Kind regards

Comment: Hi, welcome to TEX.SE! Try to import `xcolor` in your preamble adding `\usepackage{xcolor}` and after that type `\name{\textcolor{red}{xxx}}`. You can define in your preamble different colors.

Comment: Have you tried to use `\textcolor` from `\usepackage{xcolor}`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments